# Nginx Rewrite URL 404 Error

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I wanna to mask or rewrite URLs.

Currently, my app details page looks like this:

**example.com/detail/morphite-final-beta?id=com.crescentmoongames.morphite**

so I wanna that pages without "?id="  like this:

**example.com/detail/morphite-final-beta/com.crescentmoongames.morphite**

This is the code that I put in nginx configuration:

```
location /detail/ {

    rewrite ^/detail/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ /detail/$1?id=$2;

}
```

That returns 404 Not Found Errors. I create that code and try others searching answers on this page but nothing works. What is wrong?

Comment: What does the rest of your configuration look like. Particularly `location /` block?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have ? in your url , its hard to do by RegularExpression. Please try this way.

```
if ($args ~ "(^|&)id=com.crescentmoongames.morphite($|&)"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/example.com/detail/morphite-final-beta$ /example.com/detail/morphite-final-beta/com.crescentmoongames.morphite permanent;
}
```